# How do I store the value I get from a textarea box so I can copy and paste it directly to my .js file and have it be easily reproducible?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two textarea boxes on my personal page:

```
<textarea id="BoxText4Load" rows="12" cols="112" style="font-size:12pt"></textarea>

<textarea id="SecondBox" rows="12" cols="112" style="font-size:12pt"></textarea>
```

When I use javascript console to retrieve the value from one textarea, I can use DOM to quickly input to the other box.

Example:

```
var text3 = document.getElementById("BoxText4Load").value
document.getElementById("SecondBox").value = text3
```

However, if I copy and paste what Javascript console retrieves for me with document.getElementById("BoxText4Load").value into my .js file, there's formatting errors because the text might have quotation marks.  Is there a way to get the value in a format that I can copy and paste directly into my .js file?

Basically, my goal is to create a buttons where I can change what I see on my file and have different stories display through a textarea box.  I don't want to make the effort to escape quotation marks and line breaks with \n and ".

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xLqs4uo/), can you replicate the issue and share back!

Comment: @NarenMurali good job (y) :)

Comment: @jafarbtech Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2xLqs4uo/2/  After update to first box, I want to get value of the first box and put that into javascript, but how else can I retrieve the value so it doesn't get chunky.

Comment: You can use backticks `` to have the text span multiple lines. With this you no longer need to escape the characters. In your fiddle, change double quotes that wraps the text to ` and it works fine.

Comment: @Phani Kumar M  Thanks a ton!!!  The backticks did it!  https://jsfiddle.net/2xLqs4uo/3/

Answer (score 0):

What's the matter for this example?

```js
function copyText(e) {
  var text3 = document.getElementById("BoxText4Load").value
  document.getElementById("SecondBox").value = text3
}
```

```css
textarea {width: 200px;height:100px}
```

```html
<textarea id="BoxText4Load" rows="12" cols="112" style="font-size:12pt"></textarea>

<textarea id="SecondBox" rows="12" cols="112" style="font-size:12pt"></textarea>
<button onClick="copyText(event)">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){
var a = document.getElementById('BoxText4Load').value;
var b = document.getElementById('SecondBox');
b.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```css
textarea{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="BoxText4Load" rows="12" cols="112" style="font-size:12pt"></textarea>

<textarea id="SecondBox" rows="12" cols="112" style="font-size:12pt"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">ok</button>
```